# How to overlay a satellite mbtiles over a regular OSM map?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, mbtiles, tileserver-gl

I'm using [klokantech tileserver gl](https://hub.docker.com/r/klokantech/tileserver-gl) to serve OSM maps. These maps are consumed by a frontend developed using Vue and vue-leaflet. The OSM world mbtiles file works perfectly with the default config from klokan.

An asked evolution of the system is to add data to the map in the form of satellites imagery. The chosen solution (which can be a bad one) is to add another set of mbtiles containing the satellite views ([here is an example](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/r/aabb8b14-ee04-41a8-a1a8-f5c8b5bd1587)).

This new file would be made in advance and transferred to the machine using a usb key or a similar device. *It's important to note that I **do not** have access to the internet on the machine.*

I would like to overlay these satellite views (if available) over my already existing OSM maps. I tried to serve them using klokan but couldn't figure out the necessary configuration to do so.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers